# What is a command to create a file on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

For testing purposes I have to create a file with 1000 lines in it with one command.

What is a command to create a file on Linux?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should probably be on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I'd disagree. This is a general programming Q&A. How to create a file to start a testing workflow belongs here.

Comment: This link provides many types creates command in terminal http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159672/how-to-create-a-simple-txt-text-file-using-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in `seq 1 1000`; do echo "sometext" $x >>file.txt; done
```

Answer (score 2):

`touch` is usually used to create empty files, but if you want to create a non-empty file, just redirect the output of some command to that file, like in the first line of this example:

```
$ echo hello world > greeting.txt
$ cat greeting.txt
hello world
```

A way to create a file with 1000 lines would be:

```
$ seq 1000 > file
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the above for loop use print something $c times in text.txt.$c is number of runnning time (1,2,4...10000)

```
for (( c=1; c<=1000; c++ ));do echo "something $c times">>test.txt ;done
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: above for loop use print something $c times in text.txt.$c is number of runnning time (1,2,4...10000)